# What was the episode where Superman ate an entire jar of m&ms?

Tags: dc, superman, episode-identification, lois-and-clark

In the New Adventures of Superman, there was an episode where Superman, in his Clark persona, ate a lot of m&ms very quickly. I think he and others were infected or under the influence of something, causing them all to act greedy (possibly just Clark, though).

I remember the scene where Clark and another man both had a jar filled with candy (m&ms, I think). The man looked away for a second, and Clark used his super sucking power (?) to suck out all the candy from his own. When the man looked back, Clark's jar was empty, with Clark was chewing on the last bits in his mouth. The man then turned away, protecting his jar.

Can anyone help me find the episode with this scene?

Answer (score 6):

This is in Season 2, Episode 9, titled "Season's Greedings". Clark is in a company Christmas party with Jimmy Olsen. Everyone is going crazy over these toys rats filled with some infatuating substance. Lois has one and squeezes it, spraying a mist of the substance directly into Jimmy and Clark's faces.

Instantly, they become filled with the desire to have everything. They come across a snack table with two full containers of candy (they look to be Skittles). Clark distracts Jimmy (he literally says "look over there") and proceeds to suck in all the candy from the taller of the two jars. Jimmy looks back at Clark eating the last bits of a now emptied jar. He picks up the jar closest to him protectively, and they both walk away into the chaos.

Comment: The bright colors make it look more like [Skittles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skittles_(confectionery)) to me, but close enough.

Comment: Yeah, they probably are. Too bright for m&ms.